# Getting PyCharm to find dependencies under

Tags: python, pycharm, dependency-management

Is there some way to tell PyCharm where to look for files?

Here's an example, I clone this [repo](https://github.com/kimiyoung/transformer-xl), cd into `transformer-xl/pytorch` and run `train.py` and it works because `utils` is in `.` which Python interpreter includes in it's list of places it searches for imports.

However, when I open this project in PyCharm, it underlines all instances of `utils`, is there some way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. You can define folders of a project as a source:

```
Settings -> Project: YourProject -> Project Structure
```

Here mark the folders you want as Project Sources. You can also add different Projects as root folders if you needed.